# Is the linking verb 'be' always considered a stative verb?

Tags: verbs, be, stative-verbs, linking-verbs, dynamic-verbs

I got a quesiton recently which was:

> True or False: The linking verb 'be' is always considered a stative verb?

To my knowledge, the answer should be True (i.e., the verb 'be' is always supposed to be a stative verb) but in the answer section of the book, the correct answer has been provided as: 'False'. I would like to know who is right here. Furthermore, if I am wrong, please provide examples to make it clear to me.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/stative-verb-1692139#:%7E:text=Key%20Takeaways%3A%20Stative%20Verbs&text=Common%20examples%20include%20be%2C%20have,were%2C%20or%20static%20verbs) explains that there are verbs which are both stative and active:

> English also has plenty of gray areas, where a word isn't always only in one or the other category—sometimes words are stative and sometimes active. As with so many things in English, it depends on context.

***Be*** is such a verb. [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-verb-be-in-english) explains

> People’s behaviour. For this we use the continuous tenses of the verb with a suitable adjective.
>
> - I *am not **being** slow*, I am being careful.
> - You *were **being** very rude* to your mum when I came downstairs.

So in the progressive tense, ***be*** refers to temporary behaviour. There is this question about *[the usage of "being"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373061/usage-of-being)* that can give you a clearer idea about the matter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarafication. I was unable to recall any sentence in which the verb 'be' could be a dynamic/action verb. I think your example: "You were being very rude..." does just that. It shows action in a way. So, thank you for that.

Comment: '_Be good!'_' at least strongly implies a change in overall behaviour, and according to Dowty's third test [[in the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb#Difference_from_inchoative)] probably can't be considered a stative usage, while according to @John Lawler's response at [Are inchoative and causative verbs action or stative verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/526157/are-inchoative-and-causative-verbs-action-or-stative-verbs/596003#596003) the situation is complicated. I'd say JL's response is essential reading for an overview.

Comment: Imperatives invoke compliance, which is a matter of doing something, and hence have a dynamic VP, as opposed to a stative one. Imperative "be" is thus lexical not auxiliary, thus not stative.

Comment: _Be_ is always an auxiliary, and -- to the extent it has any semantic properties, which is not very much -- it's always stative. Or you can say it copies the active/stative property from the predicate it's introducing. You can say it's "active" when it's the auxiliary of an active predicate like _good_, in the behavior sense; but it's "stative" when it's the auxiliary of a stative predicate like _tall_. Except that semantic properties aren't copied onto auxiliary verbs -- they stay with their predicates.

Comment: "Be" is _predominantly_ an auxiliary, but it's also a lexical verb in imperatives and examples like "Why don't you be more tolerant?", where it behaves as a lexical verb by virtue of taking _do_ -support in present tense negatives.